# How to calculate the height of one line box height in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am so confused with this white space.When i use the inspect tool on the chrome devtools,the selected area is like this.
[image]

But, when i use cursor to select this area.It will be like this.
[image]

My font metrics is like this.
[image]

Why there is a white space at the top of "MO".I thought the picture will align at the "MO" top,not high than the top.Why?
[image]

My code is like this

```css
p {
  font-size: 100px
}

.b {
  font-family: hhnormal
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'hhnormal';
  src: url('./fontfamily/CAbnormal.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="b">MO</span><img style="font-size:0px;height:100px;vertical-align:text-top;" src="https://ss0.baidu.com/73x1bjeh1BF3odCf/it/u=1017087508,1225706513&fm=85&s=FAC1B1404FB4B24F5E51E4070000E0C9" alt="">

</p>
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe put `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` on all related CSS and see if some inherited props are trolling you, but usually those would show up as coloured borders while you have dev tools open. Try putting it on the <img>.

Comment: Interesting. The text selection should highlight the font and its line-height setting. If you change this line-height, it should probably change the height of the blue area. However, when using the devtools, you are selecting a particular span element and perhaps the line-height of text is not taken into account. Not sure if this should be of concern though as devtools is a helper for DOM inspection.